# Which index is the Z index in a 3D array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, z-index

I am having trouble understanding the correct use of a 3D array. I am using C#. My main confusion is about which index is the Z index. Unfortunately, I have done much Googling but most of the information I could find was about 2D arrays. This guy on Youtube, however, said that the third index was Z:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eqo552n1DSc

According to that tutorial, in the case of:

```
  public string[,,] array3DString = new string[2, 5, 6];
```

2 = x, 5 = y, and 6 = z.

At first this made sense, but then I tried to fill an array through loops to give myself a visual understanding: it helps me to see things visually. So I wrote this simple program:

```
class Test
    { 
        public string[,,] array3DString = new string[2, 5, 5];
        public void SetArray3DString()
        {
            for (int zIndex = 0; zIndex < 2; zIndex++)
            {               
                for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
                    {
                        array3DString[zIndex, r, c] = "z" + zIndex + "r" + r + "c" + c;                   
                    }
                }
            }
        }      
        public void PrintArray3DString()
        {
            for (int zIndex = 0; zIndex < 2; zIndex++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Z Index - " + zIndex);
                for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
                    {
                        if (c < 4)
                        {
                            Console.Write(array3DString[zIndex, c, r] + ",");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(array3DString[zIndex, c, r]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            Test newTest = new Test(); 
            newTest.SetArray3DString();
            newTest.PrintArray3DString();
            while (true);
        }
    }
```

It seemed to me that when I tried to iterate through a 3D array with loops, it made more sense for the first index to be Z, because, of course, the outer loop is the last one to get indexed. The output is this:

```
Z Index - 0
z0r0c0,z0r1c0,z0r2c0,z0r3c0,z0r4c0
z0r0c1,z0r1c1,z0r2c1,z0r3c1,z0r4c1
z0r0c2,z0r1c2,z0r2c2,z0r3c2,z0r4c2
z0r0c3,z0r1c3,z0r2c3,z0r3c3,z0r4c3
z0r0c4,z0r1c4,z0r2c4,z0r3c4,z0r4c4
Z Index - 1
z1r0c0,z1r1c0,z1r2c0,z1r3c0,z1r4c0
z1r0c1,z1r1c1,z1r2c1,z1r3c1,z1r4c1
z1r0c2,z1r1c2,z1r2c2,z1r3c2,z1r4c2
z1r0c3,z1r1c3,z1r2c3,z1r3c3,z1r4c3
z1r0c4,z1r1c4,z1r2c4,z1r3c4,z1r4c4
```

Which is what I would expect to see. When I tried making the last index Z, I just confused myself.

So am I right, or is the guy in the Youtube video right? Which index should be Z, and why? Does it even matter?

For reference, I also tried this site: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm 
but again they mainly focused on 2D arrays and did not answer this simple question for me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a rule about how you would store it. It's all about how it is serialized in the memory.

There is a difference on your code, while filling and printing:

Filling:

```
array3DString[zIndex, r, c]    <--- r = 2nd index..
```

Printing:

```
array3DString[zIndex, c, r]    <--- r = 3rd index..
```

So this doesn't crash as long a the dimensions of c and r are equal

Comment: So you're saying it doesn't matter which one I consider the Z index?

Comment: And yeah I printed them out that way so that it visually looked correct. Cheers for the prompt reply!

Comment: Personally I would avoid multidimensional arrays for this purpose. I'd rather use an one dimension array. If I want to calculate an offset I use: `((width*height) * z) + (width * y) + x` but moslty I do a linear scan.

Comment: Oh okay, well I thought it would make a difference which one was Z, I'm glad it doesn't. I'm going to be designing a level editor for a game, so I want each collision layer, each, ground / background, player / obstacles on separate z layers, so that's why I'm looking into it

Comment: Thank you for your responses :)

Comment: So, the z is a layer. The problem with multidimensional arrays is that they consume much memory. Also, all empty spots are still using memory.

Comment: Yes, Z would be a layer. I guess I just find it easier to conceptualize a mutli-dimensional arrays rather than calculating a 1D array. I've never gotten my head around that concept